# Are there any ways to model markov chains from time series data?

Tags: markov-chain, time-series

I want to make a thing that produces a stochastic process from time series data.
The time series data is recorded every hour over the year, which means 24-hour of patterns exist for 365 days.

What I want to do is something like below:

1. Fit a probability distribution using data for each hour so that I can sample the most probable value for this hour.
2. Repeat it for 24 hours to generate a pattern of a day.

**BUT!** I want the sampling to be done considering previous values rather than being done in an independent manner.

For example, I want to sample from [image: p_{h1}(x_t|x_{t-1}, x_{t-2}, ... , x_{t-k})] or just [image: p_{h1}(x_t|x_{t-1})] rather than [image: p_{h1}(x_t)] when [image: h1] refers to a specific hour.

What I came up with was the Markov chain, but I couldn't find any reference or materials on how to model it from real data.

Could anyone give me a comment for this issue?